# Other elements wrap around center positioned div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on [this page](http://yugo.ponchoalfonso.com/?p=16). As you can see, it's a squarish grid kind of layout. I was wondering if I can position an element that occupies 4 squares (2x2 in the middle), and having the other elements wrap around it, like this:

```
 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|   |_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_ _|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|_|
```

I was wondering whether this is even possible? Reliance on JavaScript (vanilla or jQuery) is tolerable for this project.

Comment: Have you considered Twitter's Bootstrap? It should be fairly easy to accomplish something like this using that framework. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: I think [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) should solve this

Comment: Here's a fiddle using CSS grid: https://jsfiddle.net/nbx37qdy/. I've just learnt how to use grid for this question so it's definitely not implemented with best practices or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QrEr5/3/

Comment: A bit more comprehensive: http://jsfiddle.net/QrEr5/1/ (Just centered the numbers xd)

Comment: Thank you very much @Billy, but I forgot to mention I'm generating the lists from PHP. The direction of the content is horizontal till it breaks and wraps on the next line

Comment: @AKG - Is that not what my demo is doing? All of the container divs are just floating left which makes the content horizontal. It breaks onto a new line when the width of the wrapper is reached.

Comment: @BillyMoat Maybe I didn't phrase my question properly... 8 'boxes' go onto one line, but I want to insert a big box of 2 x 2 boxes somewhere in the center. Your example is doing that, but it's displaying a Z pattern, if you get what I mean.